# problems installing gpu driver

Tags: drivers, ati, gpu

after running the installation of the driver i get an error that i need to install some prerequisites found in the `fglrx-install.log` file and there i found this

```
NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
Package dh-modaliases is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install dh-modaliases.
Package execstack is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install execstack.
Package dpkg-dev is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install dpkg-dev.
Package debhelper is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install debhelper.
```

And I installed everything without problem except debhelper, it gives me this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debhelper : Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa). Possibly relevant: http://askubuntu.com/a/435796/178596

Comment: i now installed the driver but i cant run dota 2, after few seconds in the game it crashes

Comment: Try https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3559. You can post on the github issue page with the terminal output of `glxinfo`, `lspci -v`, as well the output of the terminal when you run the game in it *(close any running instances of Steam, look for the game's launcher in `~/.local/share/applications` and open it in a text editor, and copy the contents of the `Exec` line into the terminal (someting like `steam steam://rungameid/440`)*

Comment: Also, there was a similar issue for TF2 https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/1841